# System.TypeInitializationException при сборке проекта Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, компиляция

При сборке проекта появляется ошибка:

```
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка      непредвиденная ошибка при выполнении задачи VerifyVersionsTask".
System.TypeInitializationException: Инициализатор типа "Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.NugetPackages" выдал исключение. ---> System.ArgumentException: Элемент с тем же ключом уже был добавлен.
   в System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   в System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   в System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   в Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.NugetPackages..cctor()
   --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
   в Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.NugetPackages.FrameworkVersionForSupportVersion(String supportVersion)
   в Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.VerifyVersionsTask.Execute()
   в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()  Hubus.Android
```

Ошибка возникла спонтанно. Пробовал собрать другие проекты и создавал новые - результат тот же.

В чем может быть дело или хотя бы в какую сторону стоит копать?

Answer (score 0):

Подобное было. Решил полным удалением пакетов xamarin из nuget и после этого установил сперва *Xamarin.Essentials* версии *1.3*, потом *Xamarin.Android.Support.Design* версии *28.0.0.1*, после этого проект больше не ругался на отсутствие ссылок, поэтому дальше экспериментировать не стал, так как всё стало компилироваться и запускаться.
Хотя изначально там были ещё *Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils Version=28.0.0.2* и *Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs Version=28.0.0.2*, но нужная версия их вроде автоматически устанавливаются вместе с *Xamarin.Essentials*

Comment: В рантайме никакие ошибки не могут возникнуть из-за отсутствия андроидовских пакетов, стоящих по умолчанию?

Comment: Утверждать ничего не могу, так как не знаком с этим настолько. По идее нужно извратить что-то наподобие ServiceLocator, чтобы статическая проверка не сработала. 
PS Сейчас попробовал добавить Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs Version=28.0.0.1 и Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils Version=28.0.0.1 - всё скомпилировалось и запустилось. Так что возможно проблема в версии 28.0.0.2

Comment: Я попробовал удалить все пакеты, причем, после удаления каждого пытался скомпилировать проект, безуспешно. Поставил пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, тоже не скомпилилось. Понизил версию всех пакетов до 28.0.0.1, также не компилится

Comment: У меня получилось именно тогда, когда я удалил все 4 дефултных пакета, и поставил Xamarin.Essentials версии 1.3, попытался скомпилировать - он у меня ругался на нехватку некоторых элементов, после этого я и добавил Xamarin.Android.Support.Design версии 28.0.0.1 - и всё пошло. В вашем же случае удаляйте и ставьте по очереди - анализируйте полученную ошибку. Обычно до успешной компиляции ваша ошибка не пропадёт. То есть нужно смотреть, что ему не хватает из другого и ставить постепенно библиотеки версии 28.0.0.1.

Comment: Да просто мне кажется, что дело в чем-то более серьезном. Все Xamarin-проекты перестали компилироваться, а не один конкретный

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема решилась после переустановки студии и связанных с ней программ (в моем случае - решарпер и syncfusion). Далее обновился до пакетов версии 28.0.0.2 - ошибка снова появилась. Однако в этот раз удалось откатиться до версии 28.0.0.1, скомпилировать и собрать решение.

**Вывод: не обновляться до 28.0.0.2, по крайней мере, пока что**

Answer (score 0):

Решил аналогичную таким образом:
- удалил все NuGet пакеты Xamarin
- установил пакет Xamarin.Essentials
При этом автоматически установились нужные пакеты, и солюшен собрался.

После этого на вкладке Updates - No packages found.